# ReactJs setState not working the this keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need the `this.setState` inside my function but I am unable to understand the process.
please see the image below

[image]

I need the `this keyword` to solve my problem

Comment: change `timeUpdating` to an arrow function so that `this` refers to your component, or, use `timeUpdating.bind(this)` to predefine what `this` will refer to in your `timeUpdating` method

Comment: I need bind I tried , ``` function timeUpdating(){
      pressWord--;
      if(pressWord===0) clearInterval(setTime);
      timeUpdating.bind(this).setState({runTime: pressWord})
    } ``` but not working man

Comment: If you read the duplicate above it will clarify my comment. But you need to use `.bind()` in the setInterval: `let setTime = setInterval(timeUpdating.bind(this), 1000)`, this will make it so the `this` inside your function refers to your component `this` rather than the global object (ie: window)